# mysql, vb.net - Saving Transaction not working

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I don't know what's the real problem since there are no error being reported. So what I want these codes to do is insert a transaction record to the database but there is nothing being returned. Here are the codes that related to this:

> MainForm

```
Private Sub PayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PayButton.Click
        Dim payment As New Payment
        payment.Show()
        AddHandler payment.PaymentEvent, AddressOf paymentSuccess
        payment.PaymentAmount = TransactionTotal
    End Sub
```

> 

```
Public Sub paymentSuccess(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Payment.PaymentMadeEventArgs)
            mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
            mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
            Try
                mydbcon.Open()
                Dim Query As String
                Query = "select * from inventory"
                COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
                reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
                While reader.Read
                    Dim itId As Integer = reader.GetString("itemid")
                    Dim itName As String = reader.GetString("itemname")
                    If e.PaymentSuccess = True Then
                        paymentSuccessQuery(itId, itName)
                    End If
                End While
                reader.Close()
                mydbcon.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Sub
```

> ```
>  Private Sub paymentSuccessQuery(ByVal itemid, ByVal itemname)
>         mydbcon = New MySqlConnection
>         mydbcon.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
>         Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
>         Try
>             mydbcon.Open()
>             Dim Query As String
>             Query = "INSERT INTO transaction (itemid, itemname) VALUES('" & itemid & "', '" & itemname & "')"
>             COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
>             reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader()
>             If reader.Read Then
>                 MessageBox.Show("Unable to save transaction!")
>             Else
>                 MessageBox.Show("Transaction Saved!")
>             End If
>             reader.Close()
>             mydbcon.Close()
>         Catch ex As Exception
>             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
>         End Try
>     End Sub
> ```
>
> Transactionform

```
Public Class Payment
    Public Delegate Sub PaymentMadeEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaymentMadeEventArgs)
    Public Event PaymentEvent As PaymentMadeEvent

    Private _paymentAmount As Decimal
    Public Property PaymentAmount As Decimal
        Get
            Return _paymentAmount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _paymentAmount = value
            AmountBox.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", _paymentAmount)
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub PayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PayButton.Click
        Dim total As Decimal = 0

        Try
            total = Decimal.Parse(AmountBox.Text.TrimStart("₱")) - Decimal.Parse(PaymentBox.Text)
        Catch
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, please enter a valid amount!")
            Return
        End Try

        If (total > 0) Then
            AmountBox.Text = total.ToString()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please give " + String.Format("{0:c}", -total))
            RaiseEvent PaymentEvent(Me, New PaymentMadeEventArgs() With {.PaymentSuccess = True})
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Class PaymentMadeEventArgs
        Inherits EventArgs
        Private _paymentSuccess As Boolean
        Public Property PaymentSuccess As Boolean
            Get
                Return _paymentSuccess
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
                _paymentSuccess = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ExecuteReader` executes the command (the insert) but it has been built to return the rows extracted by a SELECT command.
Calling `Read` to discover if your INSERT has been successful is meaningless in this context.

You should call `ExecuteNonQuery`, catch the return value, and if it is not equal to zero, then you have inserted the record.

```
Private Sub paymentSuccessQuery(ByVal itemid, ByVal itemname)
    Using mydbcon = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=sdudb"
    Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "INSERT INTO transaction (itemid, itemname) " & _ 
                "VALUES(@id, @name)"
        Using COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
           COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  itemid 
           COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =  itemname
           Dim rowsAdded = COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
           if rowsAdded = 0 Then
               MessageBox.Show("Unable to save transaction!")
           Else
              MessageBox.Show("Transaction Saved!")
           End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

Notice also the I have changed your code to use the appropriate Using statement around the disposable objects like the connection and the command and, of utmost importante, I have changed your query to use a more safe parameterized query approach (not sure about the MySqlDbType for the ID parameter, it seems to be an integer but in your original query you put it between single quotes like a string)